# Using function stack in javascript to call non-recursive method

Tags: javascript

I wanted to use the non-recursive method to call a function repeatedly. I got the following example of a non-recursive method:

```js
function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0)
    return;

  console.log('begin:' + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log('end:' + i);
}

foo(3);
```

```html
<!-- this is to make console output visible -->
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

and it gives the following output:

```
begin:3
begin:2
begin:1
begin:0
end:0
end:1
end:2
end:3
```

Can anybody make me understand that why it is printing the following lines:

```
end:0
end:1
end:2
end:3
```

Even the function returns from the line `foo(i - 1);`

Comment: This is a recursive function...............

Comment: Why do you think it is non-recursive?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com it is saying that `It is possible to convert any recursive algorithm to a non-recursive one`, but thats all to `non-recursive`.

Comment: Its because when you call a function inside a function, after returning the value parent function continues to execute remaining code

Comment: Unless it is an object or an array, you're passing by value.  Printing i in this  recursive function only shows you what i is when that particular function was called.

Answer (score 2):

Because code executed from **top** to the **bottom**, when you call function inside a function it doesn't mean that executing of parent function is stopped. It calls inner function and inner function calls inner function etc.. till the moment when the deepest function returns value in your case value is `undefined` of the deepest function.

So it prints

```
begin:3
begin:2
begin:1
begin:0
```

At this point deepest function reached and it returned `undefined` (`return;`) and it goes up, previous function before undefined had `i=0`, so the execution of function is finished and it bubbles up and execute rest of the code after calling inner function. Result:

```
end:0
end:1
end:2
end:3
```

Answer (score 0):

well, it is a recursive function because the function calls itself in its definition block.

```
foo(3) : ['begin:3', foo(2), 'end:3']
foo(2) : ['begin:2', foo(1), 'end:2']
foo(1) : ['begin:1', foo(0), 'end:1']
foo(0) : ['begin:0', foo(-1), 'end:0']
foo(-1) : []
```

if you put it all together you have the output you're describing. Imagine it like a [matryoshka doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll)...

Lets check the last 3 Lines (for simplicity I omit the newlines):

- `foo(-1)` gives no output
- `foo(0)` gives `'begin:0' + foo(-1) + 'end:0'`

  = `begin:0 end:0`
- `foo(1)` gives `'begin:1' + foo(0) + 'end:1'`

  = `begin:1 begin:0 end:0 end:1`

Comment: Its printing the `end`s in opposite order.

Comment: @putvande: no, it's not... carefully look at how those elements are assembled like a matryoshka doll...

Comment: He's reordering the events so it is clear what it prints and where it is in the stack.  I don't think he was ever implying that they weren't being printed out in the order in which they were printed out.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a processing queue instead of function call stack. Then function foo is called sequentially instead of recursively.

```
var q=[3]
function foo(x){
  ...
  q[q.length] = x-1//instead of foo(x-1)
  ...
}
while(q.length){foo(q.shift())}
```

Comment: Is this an answer? Maybe you should explain.